# How to fix Ogre3d segfault with std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance?

Tags: c++, std, ogre3d, segmentation-fault, ogre

I'm working on a 3d music visualizer using Ogre3d, basically it's a spectrum analizer, a lot like the old xmms plugin:

It works well, the bars are drawn and updated, there are no framerate issues, but it crashes randomly.
Sometimes it can run without problems, finish the song, other times it crashes instantly, other times the music just stops, without a crash.

Here is the source code for the main class :

https://github.com/balazsbela/OgreVisualizer/blob/master/src/VisualizerApplication.cpp#L221

Also the crashes seem to happen less often when I display the framerate overlay from Ogre samples.
Would limiting the framerate help ?

The crashes are seemingly random. Is it a performance issue ?

Please help me out, I'm quite lost on this one, I also posted on Ogre3d forums but I received no responses.

(http)://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=63207

Thank you.

Backtrace:

```
balazsbela@darknet:~/workspace/OgreVisualizer/Release$ gdb OgreVisualizer core
GNU gdb (GDB) 7.2-debian
Copyright (C) 2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "i486-linux-gnu".
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>...
Reading symbols from /home/balazsbela/workspace/OgreVisualizer/Release/OgreVisualizer...done.
[New Thread 17705]
[New Thread 17702]
[New Thread 17703]
[New Thread 17700]
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libv4l/v4l1compat.so
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.1...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/local/lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libfftw3.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libfftw3.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libSDL_sound-1.0.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libSDL_sound-1.0.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libOIS-1.2.0.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libOIS-1.2.0.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libm-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libm.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/libgcc_s.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libgcc_s.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libc-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libc.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libpthread-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libpthread.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libv4l1.so.0...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/local/lib/libv4l1.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libfreetype.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libSM.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libSM.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libICE.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libICE.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libX11.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libX11.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXext.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXext.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXt.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXt.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXaw.so.7...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXaw.so.7
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libdl-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libdl.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.42.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libboost_thread.so.1.42.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.42.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libboost_date_time.so.1.42.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libfreeimage.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libfreeimage.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libzzip-0.so.13...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libzzip-0.so.13
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libz.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libz.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libsmpeg-0.4.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libsmpeg-0.4.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libmikmod.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libmikmod.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libvorbis.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libvorbis.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libvorbisfile.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libvorbisfile.so.3
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libFLAC.so.8
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libogg.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libogg.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/sse2/libspeex.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/sse2/libspeex.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libasound.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libasound.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/librt.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/librt-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/librt.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libdirectfb-1.2.so.9...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libdirectfb-1.2.so.9
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libfusion-1.2.so.9...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libfusion-1.2.so.9
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libdirect-1.2.so.9...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libdirect-1.2.so.9
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libvga.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libvga.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/ld-linux.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/ld-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/ld-linux.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libv4l2.so.0...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/local/lib/libv4l2.so.0
Reading symbols from /lib/libuuid.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libuuid.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libxcb.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXmu.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXmu.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXpm.so.4...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXpm.so.4
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libjpeg.so.62
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libmng.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libmng.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libopenjpeg.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libopenjpeg.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/libpng12.so.0...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libpng12.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libIlmImf.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libIlmImf.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libImath.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libImath.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libHalf.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libHalf.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libIex.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libIex.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libIlmThread.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libIlmThread.so.6
Reading symbols from /lib/libx86.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/libx86.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/libv4lconvert.so.0...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/local/lib/libv4lconvert.so.0
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXau.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXau.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXdmcp.so.6
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/liblcms.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/liblcms.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/local/lib/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL.so...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/local/lib/OGRE/RenderSystem_GL.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libGLU.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libGL.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libGL.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXrandr.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libGLcore.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libGLcore.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/tls/libnvidia-tls.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXrender.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXcursor.so.1
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/libXfixes.so.3
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_compat.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libnss_compat-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_compat.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libnsl-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libnsl.so.1
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_nis.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libnss_nis-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_nis.so.2
Reading symbols from /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_files.so.2...Reading symbols from /usr/lib/debug/lib/i686/cmov/libnss_files-2.11.2.so...done.
done.
Loaded symbols for /lib/i686/cmov/libnss_files.so.2
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate.so...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/alsa-lib/libasound_module_rate_speexrate.so
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/sse2/libspeexdsp.so.1...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
Loaded symbols for /usr/lib/sse2/libspeexdsp.so.1
Core was generated by `./OgreVisualizer'.
Program terminated with signal 11, Segmentation fault.
#0  0xb6dc563d in std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&) ()
   from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
(gdb) bt
#0  0xb6dc563d in std::_Rb_tree_insert_and_rebalance(bool, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base&) ()
   from /usr/lib/libstdc++.so.6
#1  0xb73bb3c2 in std::_Rb_tree<Ogre::Node*, Ogre::Node*, std::_Identity<Ogre::Node*>, std::less<Ogre::Node*>, Ogre::STLAllocator<Ogre::Node*, Ogre::CategorisedAllocPolicy<(Ogre::MemoryCategory)0> > >::_M_insert_(std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, std::_Rb_tree_node_base const*, Ogre::Node* const&) ()
   from /usr/local/lib/libOgreMain.so.1.7.1
#2  0xb73b5a52 in _M_insert_unique (this=0xb6157ea0, child=0xb616aff8, forceParentUpdate=false) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_tree.h:1182
#3  insert (this=0xb6157ea0, child=0xb616aff8, forceParentUpdate=false) at /usr/include/c++/4.4/bits/stl_set.h:411
#4  Ogre::Node::requestUpdate (this=0xb6157ea0, child=0xb616aff8, forceParentUpdate=false)
    at /home/balazsbela/Downloads/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreNode.cpp:805
#5  0xb73b6a40 in Ogre::Node::needUpdate (this=0xb616aff8, forceParentUpdate=92)
    at /home/balazsbela/Downloads/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreNode.cpp:789
#6  0xb73b5038 in Ogre::Node::setScale (this=0x1825c, scale=...) at /home/balazsbela/Downloads/ogre_src_v1-7-1/OgreMain/src/OgreNode.cpp:638
#7  0x0805d306 in VisualizerApplication::adjustNodes (this=0x9cd4808) at ../src/VisualizerApplication.cpp:236
#8  0xb6e867f0 in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0
#9  0xb6e8719a in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL_mixer-1.2.so.0
#10 0xb6ed9b0d in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#11 0xb6ee185e in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#12 0xb6f2e0bd in ?? () from /usr/lib/libSDL-1.2.so.0
#13 0xb6bc7955 in start_thread (arg=0xb198ab70) at pthread_create.c:300
#14 0xb6ca6e7e in clone () at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/i386/clone.S:130
(gdb)
```

Ogre.log: http://pastie.org/1581790

Comment: This question has been reposted on the [Game Development site](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/9210/how-to-fix-ogre3d-segfault-with-std-rb-tree-insert-and-rebalance)

Answer (score 2):

I can't find line 236 in the link you posted, but this kind of segfault is usually linked to changing a STL structure while you are accessing it with an iterator in a function beneath it in the stack.